# Inject variables to string with $ not working

Tags: javascript

```
axios.get('http://192.168.0.103:3000/weather/Hourly?longitude=${coords.longitude}&latitude=${coords.latitude}')
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  dispatch(fetchWeatherDailySucceeded(result.data.weatherInfor))
})
.catch(error => {
  dispatch(fetchWeatherDailyFailed());
})
```

Somehow the string doesn't recognize my injection and the url send to the server is the whole string with ${}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`${}` works with `` backticks not with `"` or `'`

You need to use `` ( backticks)

```
`http://192.168.0.103:3000/weather/Hourly?longitude=${coords.longitude}&latitude=${coords.latitude}`
```

Or if you use `'` or `"` you can use string concatanation

```
'http://192.168.0.103:3000/weather/Hourly?longitude=' coords.longitude + '&latitude=' + coords.latitude
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject variables inside `''` or `""`. You should **``**.[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Description) says

> Template literals are enclosed by the **back-tick (``)**

```
axios.get(`http://192.168.0.103:3000/weather/Hourly?longitude=${coords.longitude}&latitude=${coords.latitude}`)
```